# Decode an OSC/UDP data package to work with the values in Python

Tags: python, sockets, types, udp, osc

Hello friendly stackExchange community.

I'm receiving OSC packages, which are UDP, to my socketserver.UDPServer. The UDP data packages look like this this:

```
b'/sample/address\x00,f\x00\x00@H\xf5\xc3'
```

I have sent this message to myself using the osc command line tool

```
oscsend localhost 9999 /sample/address f 3.14
```

so I know what to expect. The string /sample/address and a float with the value 3.14

The question is: How do I decode the bytestring above in Python so that I get the actual values in usable types?

*Disclaimer: I am well aware that there are several libraries to work with OSC data in Python. This problem is a) About the knowledge itself and b) my OSC implementation will be just a few messages and I want to do it natively without any dependencies or code from a third party (eventhough my own license will be LGPL, so don't worry)*

Answer (score 0):

You can hack together a solution using the standard `struct` module.

Comment: And if I don't know if it will be a float or a string or an int in advance?

Comment: You have to know.  You can't guess reliably just from looking at the raw string.  I don't know OSC, but you need to find some documentation about it that explains this.